# C# Grid Paging and ExtJS 4.1

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, grid, paging, extjs4.1

I am trying to implement paging toolbar on extjs grid pangel using c# backend... How do I start doing about that... I have tried using start and limit but I am not sure how it works. could someone please help me on how I can just send about 20 records per page in the grid, because my grid is getting all 500 datas, which is slowing my application as well
below is my controller that sends json to my store.. Please help

```
 public JsonResult getData(int start, int limit)
 {
   List<MyItem> items = new List<MyItem>();
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices1"].ConnectionString))
   {
     SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
     cmd.CommandText = "SELECT State, Capital FROM MYDBTABLE";
     con.Open();
     SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
     while (reader.Read())
     {
       MyItem item = new MyItem();
       item.State = reader[0].ToString(); 
       item.Capital = reader[1].ToString(); 
       items.Add(item);
     }
     con.Close();

     return Json(new {  myTable = items }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
}
```

and this is my store

```
this.store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
        autoLoad: true,
        storeId: 'mystore1',
        pageSize: 20,
        fields: [
    { name: 'State' },
    { name: 'Capital' } 
    ],
        sorters: [
            {
                property: 'State',
                direct: 'ASC'
            }],
        scope: this,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            scope: this,
            url: 'StateC/getData',
            autoLoad: { params: {
                start: 0,
                limit: 20
            }
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'myTable'
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently using MySQL & PHP so definitely error check my syntax on this, but the general logic is similar, however the syntax is a little more vague in MsSQL for the query.  I would suggest this link for the  a primer on the MsSQL recomended syntax:

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/article.php/c19611/Paging-in-SQL-Server-2005.htm

First you need to get the parameters that are passed by extjs on the ajax calls:

```
int limit = Request.QueryString["limit"];
int page= Request.QueryString["page"];
int upperBound = limit * page;
int lowerBound = limit * (page - 1) + 1;
```

I think that should work out to something like this for your query as well:

```
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY person) AS rownum, 
            MYDBTABLE.State, 
            MYDBTABLE.Capital 
        FROM MYDBTABLE
    ) AS States
WHERE  States.rownum >= {lowerBound} AND States.rownum <= {upperBound}
```

Comment: thank you for your help stephen.. I use c#. I have seen various example on PHP but I don't have any idea on how I go about doing it in c#... I am not even sure where to start with your answer. I can pass first and last from ajax call but what's the purpose of upperBound and lowerBound and then how does it calculate 'totalProperty'... is there a working example somewhere

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the start and limit values you were passing in, and the upper and lower bound's are just saying which set of 20 records to take.  Using the start and limit values you pass in, lowerBound = start, and upperBound = start + limit.  Other than that, I think that SQL query will run in MsSQL and only give you a set of 20 records.  If you use that in this query {cmd.CommandText = "SELECT State, Capital FROM MYDBTABLE";}, I think your code will work the way you are hoping.  You will need to concatenate the lower/upper bound into that to build the query as a string though.

Comment: this paging has come back and started to haunt me again... :(... should those parameters be passed from extjs... I still get the entire data on the first page and nothing on the second page even though the toolbar says page 2

Comment: Was the above approach working before? Has anything changed in the request that is being sent like it changing from a get to a post request?  Can you set a breakpoint in visual studio and make sure the sql query getting generated is valid and that everything is making it through?  Sorry for the slow reply, been on vacation for Christmas and new years.  Hope you already found a solution!

Comment: Thank you so much Stephan... yes I found a solution... the problem was on the lowerBound.... I changed it to lowerBound = start + 1... and now it works... :)